# Linux IOCTL commands

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, ioctl

Trying to implement IOCTL commands, and just encountered as below:

If `_IO` is for both read and write

than why should I consider `_IOR` and `_IOW`

any clue please ?

Answer (score 4):

Actually _IO is for ioctls that don't take any parameters at all.  For instance, say that you want to trigger a command that has been previously set up in the driver, you may not need to pass any data at all!

_IOWR is for ioctls that pass parameters in and then out. In my experience these are rare and can be confusing since one parameter is utilized for two very different purposes but it can be useful when you need it.

See the beginning of http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/ioctl-number.txt

There isn't anything in the kernel that enforces the direction, so it is mostly for documentation purposes.

Comment: Thank you Benjamin !!
I may have not taken your answer properly.
can you please clear me on "For instance, say that you want to trigger a command that has been previously set up in the driver"

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  Here's a slightly more concrete example. Say you have a device that captures data from some source.  You might have an _IOW ioctl that sets some settings: #define FOO_CONFIG _IOW(BASE, 0x0, struct foo_config).  Then, to start the data capture you have an ioctl that doesn't require any parameters: #define FOO_CAPTURE _IO(BASE, 0x0).  When the device acquires the data, it then raises an interrupt which causes the data to be transfered.

Answer (score 2):

**_IOR** --- For reading from device to user space app, **_IOW** --- Write data passed from user space app to device(Hardware) and **_IOWR** --- For both read/write data from/to device. But **_IO --- are basically used to send device configurable commands to intended device** i.e. for example if you want to read/write to flash you need to send command first and then read/write data from/to flash. Since read/write command is constant/fixed as specified in the flash datasheet, so there is no need to explicitly send/pass command from user space app to driver ioctl, you can **form a command packet as required inside _IO ioctl case and send it to flash**. _IO --- Tells that you don't have to pass data(command) from user space app, you in the driver have use hard coded read/write command and send command to the intended device. **_IOR or _IOW or _IOWR** are used read/write volatile data passed form user space app to/from device (ex:flash). Hope this answer would clarify your doubt :-).